# Efficient way to find a selector which apply on specific element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have predefined css selectors list in js array and an element. I need to find which selectors would apply on that element.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/mjALF/

*html*

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="a" id="d1">
        <div class="b"  id="d2">
            <div class="c"  id="d3">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b"  id="d4"></div>
    <div class="c"  id="d5"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
var selectors = ['#main .a', '#main .a .b', '.a', '#main .c', '#main .a .b .c'];

// pseudo code
/*

find_selectors($('#d4'), selectors);
result: null

find_selectors($('#d1'), selectors);
results: ['#main .a', '.a'];


*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to get a filtered array with [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), like this:

```
var elem = $("#d1");
var results = $.grep(selectors, function(s) { return elem.is(s); });
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HtNPu/).  Or, as a plugin!

```
$.fn.selectorMatch = function(sArray) {
    var elem = this;
    return $.grep(selectors, function(s) { return elem.is(s); });
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var results = $("#d1").selectorMatch(selectors);
```

[You can test the plugin version out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HtNPu/1/).

Comment: 111k, the biggest reputation score I have ever seen :p. Thank you.

Comment: @StoneHeart - There's more active users than me =P http://stackoverflow.com/users welcome though!

Comment: @gov - I'd watch that if I were you. Looking back at your questions, a lot of different people here have helped you. (Nothing against you Nick. +1 Nice answer.)

Comment: @gov - post all your questions anytime, there are **tons** of *extremely* smart people here at all times, for [jQuery for example](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/topusers) there are lots of active/smart users, like @patrick above :)

Comment: @patrick  i agree withyou ,yeah there are lot of brilliant people here and we get very quick answers...and i always appreciate that. I just said hi to nick like that...